# Matplotlib: Memory and 'CPU' leak

Tags: python-2.7, matplotlib, ubuntu-18.04

```
python: 2.7
Ubuntu: 18.04
matpltolib: 2.2.2
```

I have a client GUI that get information from a server and displays it. I see memory leak and change in CPU consumption with time. The picture below shows a change in CPU and memory utilization after restarting the client with GUI (~25 seconds from the right, aligned with a spice in network traffic).

The CPU graph has a dip in the CPU utilization showing that CPU usage is different before and after the restart of program.

The Memory graph shows a large drop in the memory utilization and then slight increase due to initialization of the same program.

The Network graph has a spike because the client requests all data from the server for visualization.

I suspect it is something to do with matplotlib. I have 7 figures that I rechart every 3 seconds.

I have added the image of my GUI. The middle 4 graphs are the history charts. However, I am binning all data points in 300 bins since I have ~ 300 pixels in that area. The binning is done in a separate thread. The data arrays( 2x1 000 000 points, time and value) that store the information are created from the very beginning to ensure that I don't have any memory runaway problem when my datasets grow. I do not expect the datasets to grow beyond that since the typical experiment runs at 0.1-0.01 Hz which will take several million seconds to reach the end.

Question: If it is Matplotlib, what can I do? If it is not, what else could it be?

[image: CPU and Memory consumption]
[image: The GUI cnapshot]

added Sept 6 2018:
I thought of adding another example. Here is the screenshot of CPU and memory usage after I closed the GUI. The code ran for ~ 3 days. Python 2.7, Ubuntu 18.04.1.
[image: CPU and Memory leak after 3 days]

Comment: Where's the leak? Your utilisations are practically constant. Are you sure the difference after restart is not from transient data that is not immediately available after a restart?

Comment: It looks like you start a process and this process consumed CPU and memory. That's pretty much expected. From the information provided one cannot find out what process that is and if the amount of memory/cpu usage is expected or not. Without a [mcve] of the process' code, this question also seems to not be on-topic for Stackoverflow.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi, 1) the leak is very slow and can not be seen on that scale.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest. When I start the code, I get 300Mb in RAM for this process. After some time, I see 1.7Gb. I agree with your comment regarding "... Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example ...". However, I am not sure where to start the debugging and how to approach it. Do you think i can just run plotting routing million times and see if it makes difference?

Comment: The same happens for me when I start Firefox and use it for half a day. This is pretty normal with computer programs, isn't it? So I do have severe problems understanding the question.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest, There should be a way to have the software working for weeks without rebooting. Since this is supposed to be a tool to monitor experiment I don't want to restart it every 6 hours. I have a hard time believing that the software on Hubble Telescope needs to be restarted times to time.

Comment: None of the readers of this question knows your software (and neither the Hubble Telescope software). Depending on how the code looks like, an increase in memory usage might be expected or not - noone can find out without having access to the software in use.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest, I agree. However, is there anything you would recommend to read or look at to learn more about the cause and solutions to memory leaks and increasing in CPU usage?

Comment: For starters, use at least Python3.4. There are several non-obvious situations in Python2 where memory is held due to reference cycles involving hidden finalisers, e.g. when using generators. If you cannot track down the error, using multiprocessing instead of threading may help regularly clearing memory forcefully.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you, everyone, for helpful comments. 
After some struggle, I have figure out the way to solve the problem. Unfortunately, I have made several changes in my code, so I cannot say definitively what actually helped.

Here what was done:

1. all charting is done in a separate thread. The image is saved in a buffer as a byte stream with io.Bytes() and later passed to the GUI. This was important for me to solve another problem([GUI freezes while charting with matplotlib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52206292/gui-freezes-while-charting-with-matplotlib)).
2. create a new figure(figure = Figure(figsize=(7,8),dpi=80)) each time you generate the plot. previously I have been reusing the same figure (self.figure = Figure(figsize=(7,8),dpi=80)).